# poll running for much longer than its timeout inside VM

Tags: c, virtual-machine, polling

I've got a simple C program which I've compiled on my Ubuntu 22.04 VM which is running on my MacBook via VirtualBox:

```c
#include <poll.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    int fds[2];
    struct pollfd poller = {.events = POLLIN};

    if ( pipe(fds) != 0 ) {
        perror("pipe");
        return 1;
    }

    poller.fd = fds[0];
    poll(&poller, 1, 1000);

    close(fds[0]);
    close(fds[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Clearly, `fds[0]` will never be ready for reading so `poll` should time out after 1000 milliseconds.

However, when I run

```bash
while true; do time ./a.out; done
```

I get

```
./a.out  0.01s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 9.924 total
./a.out  0.01s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 10.837 total
./a.out  0.01s user 0.01s system 0% cpu 4.070 total
./a.out  0.01s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 8.606 total
./a.out  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 1.131 total
./a.out  0.01s user 0.01s system 1% cpu 1.018 total
./a.out  0.00s user 0.01s system 0% cpu 2.682 total
./a.out  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 1.598 total
./a.out  0.01s user 0.00s system 1% cpu 1.018 total
./a.out  0.01s user 0.00s system 1% cpu 1.017 total
./a.out  0.01s user 0.00s system 1% cpu 1.055 total
./a.out  0.01s user 0.00s system 1% cpu 1.019 total
./a.out  0.01s user 0.01s system 1% cpu 1.045 total
./a.out  0.00s user 0.01s system 1% cpu 1.078 total
./a.out  0.00s user 0.01s system 0% cpu 8.336 total
./a.out  0.01s user 0.01s system 0% cpu 3.344 total
./a.out  0.01s user 0.00s system 1% cpu 1.019 total
./a.out  0.01s user 0.02s system 2% cpu 1.050 total
./a.out  0.00s user 0.01s system 1% cpu 1.022 total
./a.out  0.01s user 0.00s system 1% cpu 1.014 total
./a.out  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 2.352 total
./a.out  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 1.023 total
./a.out  0.01s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 1.323 total
...
```

Running `htop` in a separate terminal shows minimal CPU/memory usage (the VM has 4 2 gHz processors and 4 GB of RAM).

Why is `poll` producing such inconsistent behavior?

[`man poll`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) does say

> ... kernel scheduling delays mean that the blocking interval may overrun by a small amount.

However, 9 seconds over is not what I'd call a small amount.  I don't see this behavior at all on the MacBook proper so I wonder if it's due to the VM scheduling.

Comment: When I run your program on macOS Monterey 12.6.3 on an Intel MacBook Pro (16 inch, 2019), the very first time the program was run it took about 1.428s, and thereafter, it almost invariably took 1.005s or 1.006s (the times 1.009s and 1.008s appeared once each in 45 tests).  I think, but haven't proved, that applications are in some way 'phoning home' — it takes time to start them up for the first time, but that overhead vanishes as you repeatedly run the program.  So, I'm reporting "cannot reproduce".

Comment: I'm wondering if it has to do with the fact that I'm running inside of a virtual machine.  Maybe that's messing with scheduling somehow.  I don't see this behavior at all on my MacBook.

Comment: It's quite possible that a VM would modify the timing, yes.  Have you experimented at the command line in the native macOS environment?  Or are you running a VM that simulates macOS on some other host o/s?

Comment: I tried on my MacBook proper and didn't see this weird behavior.

Comment: This might be a [known issue](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=99329&p=482255&hilit=scheduling#p482255) with type 2 hypervisors like VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to be a [known issue](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=99329&p=482255&hilit=scheduling#p482255) with type 2 hypervisors like VirtualBox.  If I'm reading that link correctly, it boils down to a compounding of scheduling delays.

That is, unlike with a type 1 hypervisor, VirtualBox is running as just another program on MacOS which means that it has to wait to be scheduled itself.  Once it's scheduled, it runs its own scheduler which eventually schedules a.out.